# Switching to a latin based soft keyboard programmaticaly in android

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard, editview

Is it possible to change the user's soft keyoard selection to the English when the user focuses on a specific EditView?

If a user have installed two different languages for his soft keyboard and taps on a n EditView I would like to make sure he is going to use the English one since I want him to enter only latin characters for this field.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my further research this is not possible in current versions of Android. Actually not allowed. The user has the total control of the selection.